# Can't find "etc" folder to change php.ini

Tags: php, directory, ftp

I want to make a change in php.ini file
My php.ini should be located in /etc/php/7.4.....
But when i open  Core-FTP there is no etc-folder in the root files of my website.
How do i access or change php.ini

Comment: What kind of server are you running (ex. Apache on Ubuntu)? Do you have root access to the server or just access to your website's directory / home directory?

Comment: FTP users often don't have full file system access from the root, but are "locked" into a specific folder. What kind of scenario are we talking about here - do you have your own server, are you on shared hosting, ...?

Comment: Apache server and just access to website's directories on a shared hosting platform

Comment: If you're on shared hosting you will not be able to modify the PHP config (since it is shared with others who are using the same server). Talk to the hosting company's support if there are changes you require, and see if they will support them and add them for you.